# When I create project on android studio it shows the gradle wrapper properties not found error

Tags: android

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I create an android project it shows me the error then I have to set the gradle version manually the this error goes but after this my drawable and mipmap files got damaged please help me to solve this problem

Comment: have you tried deleting android cache folders or reinstalling android studio and SDK ?

Comment: also, try  deleting android studio cache and restart it from "File" menu